# jQuery call remote web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to call web service using jQuery and I read a lot of examples, but unfortunately I can't make it work.

I'm trying to call this web service for my exercise : http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

This is my code below, but no matter what I do, I receive errors 500 (Internal Server Error) or 400 Bad request.

```
function GetIt(){
var divToBeWorkedOn = "#AjaxPlaceHolder";
var webMethod = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit?callback=?";
var parameters = 'POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit HTTP/1.1 Host: www.w3schools.com Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 9 Celsius=5';
//var parameters = 'Celsius=5';
//var parameters = '<Celsius>5</Celsius>';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",//"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "xml", //"json"
    success: function(msg) {    
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(e){
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");              
    }
});
}
```

I'm not sure how I should pass the parameters ...

Can anybody describe where is the problem and make this example work ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function GetIt(){
  var divToBeWorkedOn = "#AjaxPlaceHolder";   
  var webMethod = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit?callback=?"; 
  var parameters = {'Celsius':'5'};

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",//"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "xml", //"json"
    success: function(msg) {    
      $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(e){
      $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");              
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it, but I receive the same error: 500 (Internal Server Error) (in Chrome)